# regex - Quotes inside of Quotes

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

I'm looking for a regular expression that can find quotes in side of quotes. I've been testing around with different options all day and I've found two that are close:

```
("([^"]|"")*")
```

For this regex, I see everything works except the quotes inside of quotes are not found. (e.g: doesn't match "Come!", "test", "test1", ... from my example below.
and

```
(\s|^)\"[[:graph:]].[^$]*?((\".[^$]*?\")*?|.[^\"])*\"\s
```

Too complex with many flaws. I think there must be a more simple solution.

I'm using a sample from Dracula to test my solution (available from project Gutenburg) (note: I've added some test quotes):

```
"Then he spoke to me mockingly, 'And so you, like the others, would play
your brains against mine. You would help these men to hunt me and
frustrate me in my designs! You know now, and they know in part already,
and will know in full before long, what it is to cross my path. They
should have kept their energies for use closer to home. Whilst they
played wits against me--against me who commanded nations, and intrigued
for them, and fought for them, hundreds of years before they were
born--I was countermining them. And you, their best beloved one, are now
to me, flesh of my flesh; blood of my blood; kin of my kin; my bountiful
wine-press for a while; and shall be later on my companion and my
helper. You shall be avenged in turn; for not one of them but shall
minister to your needs. But as yet you are to be punished for what you
have done. You have aided in thwarting me; now you shall come to my
call. When my brain says "Come!" to you, you shall cross land or sea to
do my bidding; and to that end this!' With that he pulled open his
shirt, and with his long sharp nails opened a vein in his breast. When
the blood began to spurt out, he took my hands in "test" one of his, holding
them tight, and with the other, my neck and pressed my mouth to
the wound, so that I must either suffocate or swallow some of the---- Oh
my God! my God! what have I done? What have I done to deserve such a
fate, I who have tried to walk in "test1" "test3" meekness and righteousness all my
days. God pity me! Look down on a poor soul in worse than mortal peril;
and in mercy pity those to whom she is dear!" Then she began to rub her
lips as though to cleanse them from pollution.


"Oh, no, not distressed me," she replied, "but I have been more touched
than I can say by your grief. That is a wonderful machine, but it is
cruelly true. It told me, in its very tones, the anguish of your heart.
It was like a soul crying out to Almighty God. No one must hear them
spoken ever again! See, I have tried to be useful. I have copied out the
words on my typewriter, and none other need now hear your heart beat, as
I did."
```

I expect the output to be:

```
"Then he spoke to me mockingly, 'And so you, like the others, would play
your brains against mine. You would help these men to hunt me and
frustrate me in my designs! You know now, and they know in part already,
and will know in full before long, what it is to cross my path. They
should have kept their energies for use closer to home. Whilst they
played wits against me--against me who commanded nations, and intrigued
for them, and fought for them, hundreds of years before they were
born--I was countermining them. And you, their best beloved one, are now
to me, flesh of my flesh; blood of my blood; kin of my kin; my bountiful
wine-press for a while; and shall be later on my companion and my
helper. You shall be avenged in turn; for not one of them but shall
minister to your needs. But as yet you are to be punished for what you
have done. You have aided in thwarting me; now you shall come to my
call. When my brain says "Come!" to you, you shall cross land or sea to
do my bidding; and to that end this!' With that he pulled open his
shirt, and with his long sharp nails opened a vein in his breast. When
the blood began to spurt out, he took my hands in "test" one of his, holding
them tight, and with the other, my neck and pressed my mouth to
the wound, so that I must either suffocate or swallow some of the---- Oh
my God! my God! what have I done? What have I done to deserve such a
fate, I who have tried to walk in "test1" "test3" meekness and righteousness all my
days. God pity me! Look down on a poor soul in worse than mortal peril;
and in mercy pity those to whom she is dear!"
"Come!"
"test"
"test1"
"test3"
"Oh, no, not distressed me,"
"but I have been more touched
than I can say by your grief. That is a wonderful machine, but it is
cruelly true. It told me, in its very tones, the anguish of your heart.
It was like a soul crying out to Almighty God. No one must hear them
spoken ever again! See, I have tried to be useful. I have copied out the
words on my typewriter, and none other need now hear your heart beat, as
I did."
```

for regex, I'm using grep -P (Perl) but using awk or sed would be fine as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you decide that a quote is nested rather than ending the current quote?  Is it "white space before the quote starts a new quote" (where it is assumed there is white space before the start)?  And the ending quote — white space after the quote ends the current quote?  And the quotes must be nested cleanly?  That still presents problems in a regex — you need recursion, I believe — but at least those rules seem more or less plausible.

Comment: The problem you are facing is determining whether a `"` is an embedded quote or a delimitating quote.  For example, I think you want to match the entirety of `"... When my brain says "Come!" to you, ..."`, but not the entirety of `"Oh, no, not distressed me," she replied, "but ..."`. Is that correct? What is the difference between the two? Maybe the side on which spaces appear. Would that be an acceptable way two distinguish the two?

Comment: `("([^"]|"")*")` expects `"...""Come!""..."` (CSV-style escaping)

Comment: You've identified that the first quote should include `"Come!"` and `"test"`, `"test1"` and `"test3"`, so why do you also expect those quotes to be extracted separately?  Is the single-quoted chunk to be regarded as "quoted"?  What should happen with apostrophes?  Simple ones like `don't` have no spaces around them, but `'Twas a dark and stormy night` presents problems (if single quotes are important).

Comment: If the output were what @ikegami was alluding too, I think that would be fine as well. Since I am only going to be analyzing books on Project Gutenburg, it would be okay to assume beginning quotes start with a space before the quote ` "` and ending quotes end with a space after: `" ` but even with that assumption I was having a hard time creating a regex to recognize and ignore the embedded quotes from the delimitating quotes. For now at least, I'm not worrying about single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that nested quote can be determined as the quote with a space on right side after it ("Hello here" she said.)

The following command might work:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/"[^"]*" /\n&\n/g' | grep '".*"'
```

Which gives me following output:

```
"Come!" 
"test" 
"test1" 
"test3" 
"Oh, no, not distressed me,"
```